# Media querys css - target large screens

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I am trying to make my website responsive, but when I target screens larger than 1600px the css is not working. Do I have any typo in my css code? Thank you.

```
@media (max-width:900px) and (min-width:600px) {
    ul.news li {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 3px;
    }

}


@media (max-width:1250px) and (min-width:900px) {
    ul.news li {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 3px;
    }

}

/* THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 2600px) {

    ul.news li {
        width: 100%!important;
        color: red!important;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints

Comment: The code you posted works whenever I placed it into a live example: http://codepen.io/marceloa/pen/OyRXyZ Between 1600px and 2600px, the li's are red.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can refer to this Media Query and write your css in this media query dimensions

/*=====Media Query Css Start======*/
@media all and (max-width:1920px){
}
@media all and (max-width:1600px){
}
@media all and (max-width:1366px){
}
@media all and (max-width:1280px){
}
@media all and (max-width:1024px){
}
@media all and (max-width:960px){
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
}
/*=====Media Query Css End======*/
```